# Multiplying two function handle and applying ode45 to the result

Tags: matlab, ode, function-handle

I have the following functions in discrete form (which means that they are arrays):

```
p1_1 of dim(200x1)
p1_2 of dim(200x1)
p1_3 of dim(200x1)
p2_1 of dim(200x1)
p2_2 of dim(200x1)
p2_3 of dim(200x1)
```

The functions `p1_1, p1_2, p1_3` have being evaluated a the points of `x1 = 0:(10/199):10` and the functions `p2_1, p2_2, p2_3` at the points `x2 = 0:(10/199):10`.

Since I have the function values and the points where the function was evaluated, I can do the following:

```
fun1_of_p1 = @(xq1) interp1(x1,p1_1,xq1);
fun1_of_p2 = @(xq1) interp1(x1,p1_2,xq1);
fun1_of_p3 = @(xq1) interp1(x1,p1_3,xq1);
```

and

```
fun2_of_p1 = @(xq2) interp1(x2,p2_1,xq2);
fun2_of_p2 = @(xq2) interp1(x2,p2_2,xq2);
fun2_of_p3 = @(xq2) interp1(x2,p2_3,xq2);
```

And then I need to be able to do the following:

```
new_fun1 = @(xq1,xq2) fun1_of_p1.*fun2_of_p1;
new_fun2 = @(xq1,xq2) fun1_of_p1.*fun2_of_p2;
new_fun3 = @(xq1,xq2) fun1_of_p1.*fun2_of_p3;
new_fun4 = @(xq1,xq2) fun1_of_p2.*fun2_of_p1;
new_fun5 = @(xq1,xq2) fun1_of_p2.*fun2_of_p2;
new_fun6 = @(xq1,xq2) fun1_of_p2.*fun2_of_p3;
new_fun7 = @(xq1,xq2) fun1_of_p3.*fun2_of_p1;
new_fun8 = @(xq1,xq2) fun1_of_p3.*fun2_of_p2;
new_fun9 = @(xq1,xq2) fun1_of_p3.*fun2_of_p3;
```

Finally

```
 last_fun = @(xq1,xq2) gamma1*new_fun1 + gamma2*new_fun2 +...
 gamma3*new_fun3 + gamma4*new_fun4 + gamma5*new_fun4 +...
 gamma6*new_fun6 + gamma7*new_fun7 + gamma8*new_fun8 +...
 gamma9*new_fun9;
```

The `gamma`-values are just constants (real values constants). After I have defined `last_fun`, I need to apply `ode45` to it but I don't know how to do it, I tried:

```
([T,V] = ode45(@(xq1,xq2)last_fun(xq1,xq2),tspan,x0)
```

But it doesn't work. Actually I don't know if all I have done is correct so some feedback will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think the handle of a function as a *tag* (or address, ID etc.) that identifies that function among others. These tags are numbers alright (everything in a computer is a number), but they don't represent the values the function might take. To obtain the values, you must provide the function's ID *and* the function's arguments.

Now, when you say function multiplication you mean a function that returns the multiplication of the functions' *values*, not functions' *tags*. Which leads to the correct definitions:

```
new_fun1 = @(xq1,xq2) fun1_of_p1(xq1).*fun2_of_p1(xq2);
new_fun2 = @(xq1,xq2) fun1_of_p1(xq1).*fun2_of_p2(xq2);
new_fun3 = @(xq1,xq2) fun1_of_p1(xq1).*fun2_of_p3(xq2);
new_fun4 = @(xq1,xq2) fun1_of_p2(xq1).*fun2_of_p1(xq2);
new_fun5 = @(xq1,xq2) fun1_of_p2(xq1).*fun2_of_p2(xq2);
new_fun6 = @(xq1,xq2) fun1_of_p2(xq1).*fun2_of_p3(xq2);
new_fun7 = @(xq1,xq2) fun1_of_p3(xq1).*fun2_of_p1(xq2);
new_fun8 = @(xq1,xq2) fun1_of_p3(xq1).*fun2_of_p2(xq2);
new_fun9 = @(xq1,xq2) fun1_of_p3(xq1).*fun2_of_p3(xq2);
```

Please correct also the `last_fun` expression in the same manner:

```
last_fun = @(xq1,xq2) ...
     gamma1*new_fun1(xq1,xq2) ...
   + gamma2*new_fun2(xq1,xq2) ...
   + gamma3*new_fun3(xq1,xq2) ...
   + gamma4*new_fun4(xq1,xq2) ...
   + gamma5*new_fun4(xq1,xq2) ...
   + gamma6*new_fun6(xq1,xq2) ...
   + gamma7*new_fun7(xq1,xq2) ...
   + gamma8*new_fun8(xq1,xq2) ...
   + gamma9*new_fun9(xq1,xq2);
```

The correct call to `ode45` would be:

```
[T,V] = ode45(last_fun,tspan,x0);
```

provided that `tspan` and `x0` are vectors, and `tspan` is sorted ascendingly.

Comment: Thanks four your answer! I will correct the functions right now! By the way, amazing the way you explain what the handle of a function is! Can I apply `ode45` now? How will be the correct way to formulate the code for applying `ode45` ?

Comment: The correct way would be `[T,V] = ode45(last_fun,tspan,x0)`, provided that `tspan` and `x0` have the same size and are vectors.

Comment: Thanks again! I will check your suggestions! :)

Comment: @SergioHaram Glad that I could help. :-)